# How to input a path by python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import xlrd
path = input('enter the path')
data = xlrd.open_workbook(r'path)
```

The program doesn't work ,the reason is `'path'` does not exist.
So what is the correct way to write the code?

Comment: You are trying to open a file with the literal name "path", not one whose name is stored in the variable `path`.

Comment: that's the point,python thought 'path' is str instead of var,what is the correct way to do it

Comment: Do you really not know the difference between a string literal and a variable?

Comment: of course I know the difference from them,I wanted to give a var ,but python thought it is a str...

Comment: Because it *is* a string; you put `path` in quotes, which makes it a string literal.

Comment: I know python thought i give a string instead of a path,so what is the proper way to let it understand it is a path?

Comment: You use `xlrd.open_workbook(path)`, using a variable, not a string literal.

Comment: thx dude,it works now,i was so stupid...

Answer (score 3):

```
import xlrd
path = input('enter path:')
data = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
```

This is supposed to work, your issue is you pass a string that just says 'path' instead of the path variable that has the path.
You can use a relative or absolute path.

Comment: can you give me the correct way to achieve it?

Comment: The example there works, as long as you enter the correct path when prompted by input()

Comment: it really doesn't work,I promise I gave the correct path.

Comment: I tested it and it works, so for an easy way to do it you can put the python script in the same directory as the .xlsx you're trying to open, and then just type in the name of the file. Do note the names are case sensitive.

Comment: i alreday put the .xls file and .py file in the same folder,but still doesn't work,Idle prompt "File not found'',obviously python think i gave a string instead of a path.

Comment: What, *exactly*, did you type at the `enter path:` prompt?

Comment: @user11313772 I had a file named Financial Sample.xlsx and i typed that exactly, same characters, including the space.
I would guess you either added an extra space in front, or had the wrong characters (i.e. didn't input uppercase chars as uppercase)